# Adding 1 day to my time

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have kind of an odd situation, but here goes. Im trying to tell if one time is between two others. I got that working. The problem is, the second time is going to be in the next day. So for example The first time will be 8 pm, and the second time will be 8 am. And the problem is when I compare the two times, the computer thinks that the 8am is before the 8 pm. So this is my main question. How coan I make it so that the second day is a day after the first, or tomorrow in a sense. like if today is the first, the first time would be 8 pm the first, but the second time would be 8 am the second.

---

## Edit

My code so far

```
NSDate *notificationDate = 
     [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:data.postureInterval sinceDate:[NSDate date]];

if([notificationDate compare:data.sleepModeBegin] == NSOrderedDescending &&
   [notificationDate compare:data.sleepModeEnd] == NSOrderedAscending) 
{
     NSLog(@"IT works");
}
```

notification to happen = 8:30 pm

data.sleepModeBegin = 8 pm

data.sleepModeEnd = 8 am

I want it so that  it logs it works, but because the second one is 8 am, it thinks its that morning when I want tit to be tomrrow morning

---

## Edit

My code after Martins answer

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComponents setDay:1];
    NSDate *sleepEndTomorrow = [cal dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:data.sleepModeEnd options:0];
    
    NSDate *notificationToHappen = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:data.postureInterval sinceDate:[NSDate date]];
    
    NSLog(@"%@", notificationToHappen);
    NSLog(@"%@", data.sleepModeBegin);
    NSLog(@"%@", data.sleepModeEnd);
    NSLog(@"%@", sleepEndTomorrow);
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSDate date]);

    if (([notificationToHappen compare:data.sleepModeBegin] == NSOrderedDescending) && ([notificationToHappen compare:sleepEndTomorrow] == NSOrderedAscending) ) {
        NSLog(@"HEY");
    }
```

The first datepicker is set at 3 pm

the second datepicker is set at 8 am

the output is

```
2013-09-07 16:04:22.981 MyPosturePal[40145:a0b] 2013-09-07 20:15:22 +0000
2013-09-07 16:04:22.982 MyPosturePal[40145:a0b] 2013-09-06 19:00:41 +0000
2013-09-07 16:04:22.982 MyPosturePal[40145:a0b] 2013-09-06 12:00:41 +0000
2013-09-07 16:04:22.982 MyPosturePal[40145:a0b] 2013-09-07 12:00:41 +0000
2013-09-07 16:04:22.983 MyPosturePal[40145:a0b] 2013-09-07 20:04:22 +0000
```

Comment: If you use `NSDate` objects, this shouldn't be an issue. You can then use the `compare` method to compare them, `NSDateFormatter` to format them in the `@"h a"` to yield `@"8 am"`, etc.

Comment: It is difficult to answer your question without more information how your times are stored. - You should use `NSDate`, which represents "date + time". For calculations such as "adding one day" you should read ["Performing Calendar Calculations"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW1) in the "Date and Time Programming Guide".

Comment: I am using the compare method, ill upload my code

Comment: What are the values of `notificationToHappen`, `sleepModeBegin` and `sleepModeEnd`? What result do you get and what do you expect? - Please try to provide complete information, so that you can get meaningful answers!

Comment: Sorry bout that, edited question

Comment: @user2757277 show actual code. How are you creating those date objects? Providing only the time without a date looks weird.

Comment: The data varaible are just dates from a date picker, and I have justset an example to what they would most likely be and when it would cause my problem

Comment: the date picker is set to just time

Comment: So your use case is to choose a time in a 24h range from now? In other words you have a picker view, it's 8pm. If I select 9pm it means **today at 9pm**, whereas if I select 7pm it means **tomorrow at 7pm**? Rather confusing

Comment: not sure what you mean, but i think so, so the 8 am would be tomorrow

Comment: Check my edited comment. If I select 9pm it means today at 9pm, whereas if I select 7pm it means tomorrow at 7pm?

Comment: only on the second date (data.sleepModeEnd) should it be the next day

Comment: yes, but If I select 9pm and right now it's 5pm it should be today. Correct?

Comment: In other words: explain your problem **clearly**. *I have two date pickers allowing the user to select [...] and I'm trying to [...] and it doesn't work as expected because I get [...] when doing [...]*. Improve your question, since so far it's impossible to answer.

Comment: the data.sleepmodebegin should have a date of today, and the data.sleepmode end should have a date of tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSDate` represents an absolute point in time (including the day).
 A date picker in "time only" mode returns
the selected time together with the "current day".

If you want to add one day, use `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents`:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setDay:1];
NSDate *sleepEndTomorrow = [cal dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents 
                                  toDate:sleepEndToday options:0];
```

Comment: Actually I hit a problem again. The time is logging the time at the next day, but when I go to compare them, it acts the same as before. Ill upload my code to show you what I have now.

Comment: @user2757277: You forgot to add the NSLog output as well.

Comment: @user2757277: (The NSLog output of an NSDate displays the date always in GMT time, that is no error.) - Can you add the output of `data.sleepModeEnd` as well? What values to you expect?

Comment: oh... whoops thanks, but thats not the problem. The problem is when their compared, you can see that "HEY" isnt being logged

Comment: @user2757277: `notificationToHappen = 2013-09-07 19:43:34` is *later* than `sleepEndTomorrow = 2013-09-07 12:00:41`, therefore nothing is logged.

Comment: 2013-09-07 15:48:06.905 MyPosturePal[40081:a0b] 2013-09-07 19:59:06 +0000

2013-09-07 15:48:06.905 MyPosturePal[40081:a0b] 2013-09-06 19:00:41 +0000

2013-09-07 15:48:06.906 MyPosturePal[40081:a0b] 2013-09-07 12:00:41 +0000

Comment: @user2757277: Can you please show the output of `NSLog(@"%@", data.sleepModeEnd);` ?

Comment: sure, i updated it. But I also notice that they sleepModeEnd and begin are saying the 6th and the date is saying the 7th. Also, shouldnt the sleepEndTomorrow be the 8th?

Comment: @user2757277: Strange :-) Are sleepModeBegin/sleepModeEnd the `date` values from the picker? Have you somehow modified the timezone or calendar property of the date pickers?

Comment: ok... so something went wrong when the actual date was set. So i reset the simulator and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score -4):

You could convert your times to epoc seconds - nstime method timeIntervalSince1970 would be the answer for objective-c.

Comment: Could you explain a little more on how to do this?

Comment: Converting between seconds and days is actually surprisingly tricky. Days are not always the same length! Let NSDateComponents handle it for you instead.